# Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8

Xcode log show the above error while running in Xcode 8.1, ios 10.1. Is there any problem or should I ignore and continue?

Comment: Me too. I am not sure what's root cause.

Comment: I'm getting the same result when using all simulator devices, across all versions of iOS. No idea what it means. Xcode seem to be cluttering up the console with a lot of crap like this lately..

Comment: I had to roll back my SDK version to 4.17.0. The older parse libraries I was using have not been updated to use the new save to user defaults. Hope this helps someone still using the old parse SDK.

Comment: Are you using an UIButton or FBSKButton ? When I changed from FBSDKButton to an UIButton it worked. Would you mind to try it ?

Answer (score 23):

I have this problem, too. It seems to be caused by an the Facebook SDK's Login Access Token. It caches just fine on a real device, but not on the simulators. Try running the app from a physical device.

Comment: My React Native app continues to run just fine on the physical device. Is there any fix to get it running again on the simulator?

Comment: Try uninstalling it on the simulator and running again. I can get it to work, but I have to uninstall it each time. Your results may vary.

Answer (score 12):

You can ignore this warning, it's hard coded in the FacebookSDK when using the iOS Simulator. The SDK does contain a bug though which prevents the simulator from caching the access token.

You can fix this by adding the following line:

`key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_fix", key];`

in `FBSDKKeychainStore.m:94` and `FBSDKKeychainStore.m:135` just before:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key];`

Comment: I can't seem to locate that file in my filesystem. Is this still accurate with version React Native >=0.37?

Comment: I don't know which version React Native is using. I'm referring to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/f7531a838a1ec3308721f335e801ac9f508feee4/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/TokenCaching/FBSDKKeychainStore.m.

Comment: Is this really a fix? You're still storing the key in `NSUserDefaults`.  I would only consider this a fix if you're able to provide a solution that modifies the code to work in the simulator the same way it would on a real device

Comment: where can i found FBSDKKeychainStore.m file?

Comment: @gowtham in project, you can search it with `CMD + Shift  + O`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
I tried to run in real device and this show error with OAuth Login
Then I just turn OAuth Login on and everything works well
[image: Turn on OAuth Login]

Comment: how did you even test the login status before the problem if it was disabled for OAuth Login?